# Why is Java giving me an IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, dwr

I'm using dwr and spring and I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Javascript name * is used by 2 classes
```

I found nothing helpful on Google, do you know why I'm getting this error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"

       http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
       http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">

<dwr:configuration />
<dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="true" />

    <bean id="ping" class="com.mycompany.Ping">
        <dwr:remote javascript="rpcPing">
            <dwr:include method="ping" />
        </dwr:remote>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: That is neither valid nor well-formed XML.

Comment: Where is Java getting involved in this?  This is Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found.
Because the version of the DWR's jar did not match the version of DWR's schema

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was that the relevant snippets in dwr.xml were there twice.

```
<create creator="new" javascript="Tab">
  <param name="class" value="org.openxava.web.dwr.Tab"/>
</create>
...
<create creator="new" javascript="Tab">
  <param name="class" value="org.openxava.web.dwr.Tab"/>
</create>
```